# Counting observations with duplicate ID's

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that I am converting from wide to long format.

Currently I have 1 observation per patient, and each patient can have up to 5 aneurysms, currently recorded in wide format.

I am trying to re-arrange this dataset so that I have one observation **per aneurysm** instead. I have done so successfully, but now I need to label the aneurysms in a new variable called `aneurysmIdentifier`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbrrt.jpg) is a glimpse at the data. You can see how, when a patient has 4 aneurysms, I have successfully created 4 corresponding observations, however these are duplicates created via the `expand` function.

I am stuck at the next point, which, as mentioned, is creating a new variable `aneurysmIdentifier` that reads 1 if there is only one copy of the specific `record_id`, 1 and 2 if there are two copies and so forth all the way to 1-2-3-4-5. This would enable me to have a point of reference as to what I call aneurysm 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 so I can keep re-arranging data to fit as such.

I have created [this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFq3z.jpg) hopefully showcasing what I mean. As you can see it counts how many duplicates there are and then counts forward up to the maximum of 5.

Can anyone push me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Example of data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str32 record_id float aneurysmNumber
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" 1
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" 1
"0142103f84693c6eda416dfc55f65de1" 1
"0153826d93a58d7e1837bb98a3c21ba8" 1
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" 2
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" 2
"01dd90093fbf201a1f357e22eaff6b6a" 1
"0208e14dcabc43dd2b57e2e8b117de4d" 1
"0210f575075e5def7ffa77530ce17ef0" 1
"022cc7a9397e81cf58cd9111f9d1db0d" 1
"02afd543116a22fc7430620727b20bb5" 1
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" 2
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" 2
"041b2b0cac589d6e3b65bb924803cf1a" 1
"0536317a2bbb936e85c3eb8294b076da" 1
"06161d4668f217937cac0ac033d8d199" 1
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" 4
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" 4
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" 4
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" 4
"07196414cd6bf89d94a33e149983d102" 1
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" 4
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" 4
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" 4
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" 4
"07bef516d53279a3f5e477d56d552a2b" 1
"08678829b7e0ee6a01b17974b4d19cfa" 1
"08bb6c65e63c499ea19ac24d5113dd94" 1
"08f036417500c332efd555c76c4654a0" 1
"090c54d021b4b21c7243cec01efbeb91" 1
"09166bb44e4c5cdb8f40d402f706816e" 1
"0930159addcdc35e7dc18812522d4377" 1
"096844af91d2e266767775b0bee9105e" 1
"09884af1bb9d59803de0c74d6df57c23" 1
"09e03748da35e9d799dc5d8ddf1909b5" 1
"0a4ce4a7941ff6d1f5c217bf5a9a3bf9" 1
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" 2
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" 2
"0a73c992955231650965ed87e3bd52f6" 1
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" 3
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" 3
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" 3
"0af333ae400f75930125bb0585f0dcf5" 1
"0af73334d9d2166191f3385de48f15d2" 1
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" 2
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" 2
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" 2
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" 2
"0b3e110c9765e14a5c41fadcc3cfc300" .
"0b6681f0f441e69c26106ab344ac0733" 1
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" 3
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" 3
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" 3
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" 2
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" 2
"0ba961f437f43105c357403c920bdef1" 1
"0bb601fabe1fdfa794a5272408997a2f" 1
"0c75b36e91363d596dc46bd563c3f5ef" 1
"0d461328a3bae7164ce7d3a10f366812" 1
"0d4cc4eb459301a804cbef22914f44a3" 1
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" 2
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" 2
"0d513c74d667f55c8f4a9836c304149c" 1
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" 2
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" 2
"0db9ae1f2201577f431b7603d0819fa6" 1
"0dd8a681f6a5d4c888831a591e57a747" 1
"0e05d6958d878368b5fb831211fad6a1" 1
"0e3ff41e0e2b2cb5ec336fd0b04e5d44" 1
"0f61e560ab56b8fea1f2593d7d3b2718" 2
"0f61e560ab56b8fea1f2593d7d3b2718" 2
"0f69f1f998984d37f133185179d63c60" 1
"1037032886a93e66406a4c910d1ef747" 2
"1037032886a93e66406a4c910d1ef747" 2
"1044b81b354b420e85ae835ea07de2d6" 1
"10620fc488346291281212a404681386" 1
"1074389c469944edf026d193a55b1148" 1
"1090d5a678119b03cddab609289a4d3c" 1
"111eebb45cef2211a2a2ff0219095e6a" 1
"11ddcbc8de8ef56cbc578fc81b602ffc" 1
"11f22488513cf717c333786c789b0289" 2
"11f22488513cf717c333786c789b0289" 2
"121552b22cee2a1eb4360b4d2534cd39" 1
"1251d707c5dc9243dc45d04beb7c3493" 1
"125689659bb3821fa81698dd72462773" 1
"127ba572433921c5bb408fc62eb9b5d7" 1
"129bea3f73e84e37d77d55fadfeb49dd" 1
"12e8dc6fb87822be26d6678cee9644f5" 1
"12f05a65f771c9675c2c5e9cdbfc33d1" 2
"12f05a65f771c9675c2c5e9cdbfc33d1" 2
"13d2bc86f1a19ed2959cd7354bc92d1d" 1
"13db5ede38e2ae1da17884c9a18df202" 1
"13f946e50df8ad74d7cf9fa05b4ad05b" 1
"146c4b8be7996a9789873fe55a47ab41" 1
"147fadd87da13a0271225d944d2a5e98" 1
"14a1dcfa015343bbefaac9a3a45769e5" 2
"14a1dcfa015343bbefaac9a3a45769e5" 2
"14d1377f74a63ffa29db2d99e7f6a1ce" 1
"150017d944a87b4c61f90034380c0659" 1
"150f6ca1ea453260eabf3472d3ebcad1" 1
end
```

Comment: I am downvoting this time. In a comment on your previous question I guessed that a downvote was a reaction to "the lack of a reproducible data example or of much attempt to find out suitable code, or even ... lack of formatting" and that got agreement from 3 people. Now it's my reaction. Your images are intended to be helpful, but in practice: it's too much like hard work to go back and forth between an image and your wordy question. Stata questions should be strong on concrete data examples (realistic if not real) and attempts at code and self-contained. Put everything in your question.

Comment: Of course. I have included an example of all data needed to solve the question.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. You can go `bysort record_id: gen aneurysm_id = _n` but the results will be arbitrary unless there is some other information, say a date variable, to provide a rationale for the ordering.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to even order by, but date is a good idea, thank you. The abovementioned tiny snippet of code did however do exactly what I was asking for so you can post it as answer.

Comment: OK. I reversed my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go

```
bysort record_id: gen aneurysm_id = _n
```

but the results will be arbitrary unless there is some other information, say a date variable, to provide a rationale for the ordering. Let's suppose that there is a date variable `date` that is numeric and in good order. Then

```
bysort record_id (date) : gen aneurysm_id = _n
```

would be a suitable modification. For date read also date-time if time of day is noted and notable.

Comment: Thank you, Nick, that works wonderfully. Your help has been invaluable in getting me forward with this otherwise tangled dataset.